# Checking uniform continuity of distance function

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A\subseteq X$. Define the function $f(x)$ to be $$f(x)=d(x,A)=\inf_{y\in A}d(x,y)$$
I can easily show that this function is continuous. Will it also be uniformly continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $x,y\in X$ and for $z\in A$, $d(x,A)\leq d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$, so $d(x,A)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$, take $\inf$ to $z\in A$, we have $d(x,A)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,A)$, so $d(x,A)-d(y,A)\leq d(x,y)$. Symmetry gives $d(y,A)-d(x,A)\leq d(y,x)=d(x,y)$, so $|d(x,A)-d(y,A)|\leq d(x,y)$.